# How to use the ADODB.Command with the recordset in Classic Asp

Tags: asp-classic, adodb, jscript, activexobject

So here's the situation. I tried to use a quick way to get info from my database and put it in a table. Apparently, if I ask too much info from the following select, it just won't work.

```
<%
var myConn, myRec, refCo, myCmd;
refCo = Request.querystring("refC");
Response.Write(refCo);

myConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
myRec = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
myCmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");

myConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/inetpub/wwwroot/unsite/database/world2003.mdb;");
/* myCmd.ActiveConnection = myConn;
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT NameCountry, Capital, Language, Area, Population, Descripton FROM COUNTRIES WHERE NumCountry = " + refCo";
myCmd.Execute(); */

myRec.Open("SELECT NameCountry, Capital, Language, Area, Population, Descripton FROM COUNTRIES WHERE NumCountry = " + refCo,myConn);%>
```

See the myRec.Open? It does not allow me to go pass Capital. It just won't. I figured that maybe it was too much and to go with the longer form, meaning a ADODB Command. Say I take off the comments and use myCmd, it won't work at all. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why bother using an `ADODB.Command` if your going to pass parameters unsecurely in the first place? The whole point of of using the Command object is to generate parametrised queries that will protect your application from SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not because of the number of items in the select list, but because you have a reserved word `Language` as a field name. You could rename the field to something else or escape it as `[Language]`.

Change your query to:`SELECT NameCountry, Capital, [Language], Area, Population, Descripton FROM COUNTRIES WHERE NumCountry = " + refCo` and it should work

See this:  [List of reserved words in Jet 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738)